# Error when trying to query by file id in GAPI Drive v3 using Python's library

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm using service.files().list() and providing a query string to retrieve files that match the ids in a given list. Yet Calling service.files.list errors out, and GAPI returns an error code of 400. I'm using a service object created using an access token.

I get the following message:

```
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=50&fields=%2A&q=id+contains+%271234%27&spaces=drive&alt=json returned "Invalid Value". Details: "Invalid Value">
```

Here's the code. Is it possible to query by file id in the list API? I prefer to do it this way instead of making a get request for each individual file.

```
    # Create file query string
    queryStr = ""
    for i in range(len(fileIds)):
        queryStr += f"id='{fileIds[i]}'"
        if i != len(fileIds) - 1:
          queryStr += " or "

    # Build files array
    results = service.files().list(
      pageSize=50,
      fields="*",
      q=queryStr,
      spaces="drive"
    ).execute()
    print(results.get("files", [0])[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to search on `id contains`

If you check the documentation [File query terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms#operators)

You will find that Id is not a searchable field.

Try something like `name contains car` for example